# Iterating over 2 lists at once and comparing the elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is just a small part of my homework assignment. What im trying to do is iterate through list1 and iterate backwards through list2 and determine if list2 is a reversed version of list1. Both lists are equal length.

example: `list1 = [1,2,3,4]` and `list2 = [4,3,2,1]`. list2 is a reversed version of list1. You could also have `list1 = [1,2,1]` and `list2 = [1,2,1]` then they would be the same list and also reversed lists.

Im not asking for exact code, im just not sure how i would code this. Would i run 2 loops? Any tips are appreciated. Just looking for a basic structure/algorithm.

edit: we are not allowed to use any auxiliary lists etc.

Comment: Write some code and post a specific question if/when you get stuck.

Comment: `list1 == list(reversed(list2))`

Comment: `list1 == list2[::-1]`

Comment: `all(a == b for a, b in zip(list1, list2[::-1])`

Comment: @PeterWood sorry forgot to mention we cant use extra lists and such. I had a solution already working but then i saw that condition on the assignment. Can only use the 2 lists we are given

Comment: `all(list1[index] == list2[len(list2) - index - 1] for index in range(len(list1)))`

Comment: @PeterWood or, `all(a == b for a,b in zip(list1, reversed(list2)))`

Comment: Note that the optimal version of your HW task scans every element of the list only once, not twice as a naive `list1 == list(reversed(list2))` would do. Index access is key.

Comment: @9000, to solve this what about `n = len(lst); lst[:n//2] == lst[:-(n+1)//2:-1]`

Comment: @jp_data_analysis that would work for a "palindrome", not the same case unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is that whenever you have an element `list1[i]`, you want to compare it to the element `list2[-i-1]`. As required, the following code creates no auxiliary list in the process.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [3, 2, 1]

are_reversed = True

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] != list2[-i - 1]:
        are_reversed = False
        break
```

I want to point out that the built-in `range` does not create a new list in Python3, but a `range` object instead. Although, if you really want to stay away from those as well you can modify the code to use a while-loop.

You can also make this more compact by taking advantage of the built-in function `all`. The following line instantiate an iterator, so this solution does not create an auxiliary list either.

```
are_reversed = all(list1[i] == list2[-i - 1] for i in range(len(list2))) # True
```

Comment: "we are not allowed to use any auxiliary lists etc."

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate backwards on the second list, and keep a counter of items from the start of the first list. If items match, break out of the loop, otherwise keep going.

Here's what it can look like:

```
def is_reversed(l1, l2):
    first = 0

    for i in range(len(l2)-1, -1, -1):
        if l2[i] != l1[first]:
            return False

        first += 1

    return True
```

Which Outputs:

```
>>> is_reversed([1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1])
True
>>> is_reversed([1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,2])
False
```

Although it would be easier to just use builtin functions to do this shown in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get the N'th value of each list you can do a for loop with

```
if (len(list1) <= len(list2):
    for x in range(0, len(list1):
        if (list1[x] == list2[x]): 
            #Do something
else:
    for x in range(0, len(list2):
        if (list1[x] == list2[x]): 
            #Do something
```

If you want to check if each value of a list with every value of another list you can nestle a for loop

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if (list1[i] == list2[j]):
            //Do something
```

EDIT: Changed code to Python

Comment: What does `list1.length` do?

Comment: I don't think this is Python.

Comment: Changed it to Python, didn't see the Tag.

Comment: This is still not Python: the code uses `===` and assumes that the `x` in `for x in list1` is an index (it is not).

Comment: @JariR Python uses the equivalent of Java for-each loops. Your first for-loop has logic error.